# How can I sum multiple NUMERIC fields in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, operators

I have the following table, where all the numbers are NUMERIC:

| Campaign_cost_month | LinkedIn_Ads_1 | LinkedIn_Ads_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021.01 | 85.46 | 12.37 |

I want to sum multiple fields (here I only show two of them) into a total field, like this:

| Campaign_cost_month | LinkedIn_Ads_1 | LinkedIn_Ads_2 | Total_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021.01 | 85.46 | 12.37 | 97.83 |

I tried to use ordinary operators like this, but it gives empty results for the Total_cost:

```
SELECT 
Campaign_cost_month,
LinkedIn_Ads_1,
LinkedIn_Ads_2,
LinkedIn_Ads_1 + LinkedIn_Ads_2 AS Total_cost
FROM dataset
```

Comment: cannot reproduce this. you might want to provide more details on your use case

Comment: I just tried this exact example and it worked perfectly for me, it's not an empty result, check your types.

Comment: It worked if I added the value "0" to all empty fields... Is there a way to make it work if any fields are empty?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
Campaign_cost_month,
LinkedIn_Ads_1,
LinkedIn_Ads_2,
COALESCE(LinkedIn_Ads_1,0) + COALESCE(LinkedIn_Ads_2,0) AS Total_cost
FROM dataset
```

[COALESCE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#coalesce) returns the value of the first non-null expression.
eg: COALESCE(a,b), here it will use value `a`
but if it is NULL then it will use value `b`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to sum **multiple fields** (here I only show two of them) into a total field

Consider below approach

```
create temp function custom_sum(arr array<float64>) as ((
  select sum(value) from unnest(arr) value
));
select *, custom_sum([LinkedIn_Ads_1, LinkedIn_Ads_2, LinkedIn_Ads_3]) Total_cost
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

As you can see here - you don't need to take care of handling NULLs for each column separatelly - rather you just provide your columns in the array and UDF takes care of you :o)

As an additional benefit of this approach - it is easy can be refactor into dynamically building that array - so you don't need to do it manually - check my other posts - I have plenty of example of this approach